# Not able to see field value in custom button class

Tags: apex

I am not able to see some standard as well as custom fields of OpportunityLineItem when querying from custom button's class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your profile has proper FLS (Field-level-security) for the object. If you lack read and edit access on any field, it will not show up on your VF pages, even if you've queried for it